# AWS CDK: How can I create an alias of a record in the same hosted zone?

Tags: amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an alias in my hosted zone for a non-www to point to a www record.

In console, I just create an A record, set it as an alias, and choose `Alias to another record in this hosted zone`  but I don't see a way to do this in the CDK.

This won't work as it's not an IP address:

```js
    // Add non-www alias for domain
    const _nonWwwARecord = new ARecord(this, 'non-www-to-www', {
      zone: _prodHostedZone,
      target: RecordTarget.fromValues(`www.${DOMAIN}`),
      ttl: Duration.minutes(5),
    });
```

I get:

> [Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address)

If I attempt to use `RecordTarget` from `@aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets` I don't see any options for a record in the same hosted zone.

Not sure why this is so confusing but I cannot seem to get past this...

It may help to understand that the www record is set by `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `@aws-cdk/aws-rout53-targets` currently doesn't include a target for another Route 53 record.

In the meantime you can unblock yourself with a custom implementation for `bind()`:

```ts
// Create a A record that is an alias for `otherRecord`
new ARecord(this, 'Alias', {
  zone: myZone,
  target: RecordTarget.fromAlias({
    bind: () => ({
      dnsName: otherRecord.domainName,
      hostedZoneId: myZone.hostedZoneId,
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: I tried this using C# by overriding the `Bind` method but can't get it work, has anyone had any luck?