# How to add a Route53 alias to an existing Route53 entry?

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-route53

I have a DNS entry already in Route 53.  In my CDK stack, I want to set up an alias (effectively a CNAME), so I have a new DNS entry pointing to the existing one.  For example, I want to make `new.example.com` point to `existing.example.com`, where `example.com` is hosted in Route 53 and `existing` is already set up and working.

Through the AWS console I would just create a new `A` or `CNAME` record for `new.example.com` and set it as an alias of `existing.example.com` and it would be fine, so I am trying to replicate this in CDK.

In the [CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53_targets.Route53RecordTarget.html), it says I can do this:

```
declare const zone: route53.HostedZone;
declare const record: route53.ARecord;
new route53.ARecord(this, 'AliasRecord', {
  zone,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.Route53RecordTarget(record)),
});
```

However, the docs don't say how to populate the `record` variable.

If I look at the [`route53.ARecord` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.ARecord.html), there doesn't appear to be a way to look up an existing record.

The closest I could find is using one of the other `RecordSet.fromXXX()` functions instead of `fromAlias`, however there doesn't appear to be one that can look up host names:

```
...
target: cdkRoute53.RecordTarget.fromValues('target.example.com'), // doesn't work
```

Unfortunately, `RecordTarget.fromValues()` only accepts an IP address.  If you put a hostname in, it tells you:

> Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address) encountered with 'target.example.com'

So it looks like I can only create the alias if I also created the target records in the same stack - there doesn't appear to be a way to load an existing record, so you can pass it in as the target for the new alias.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround in the meantime thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67634013/308237).  Since then they added the functionality that was missing, but it looks like they didn't provide lookups so that workaround still applies.

The solution is to provide a `bind()` function instead that provides the necessary information:

```
const route53entry = new cdkRoute53.ARecord(this, 'dns', {
  recordName: 'new.example.com',
  zone: hostedZone,
  target: cdkRoute53.RecordTarget.fromAlias({
    bind: () => ({
      dnsName: 'existing.example.com',
      hostedZoneId: hostedZone.hostedZoneId,
    }),
  }),
});
```